# What is an example analytic expression for a function whose plot qualitatively looks as follows?

Tags: functions

What is an example analytic expression for a function whose plot qualitatively looks as follows?

[image]

Here, I mean that the function asymptotes to $y=0$ for $x\to -\infty$ and $x\to +\infty$.

Comment: Try this $$x e^{-x^2}$$

Comment: @Physor Nice, thanks! Thinking in that direction, I guess something like $\frac{x}{1+x^2}$ should work as well...

Comment: You can plot all functions you want online , for example here https://www.desmos.com/calculator?lang=en

Comment: @Physor That's an awesome resource, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is odd.
it has two extremas.
it has two inflection points.
It could be defined by

$$f(x)=\frac{x}{1+x^2}$$

Comment: Man, you got +1

Comment: @Physor technically, you posted your comment with exp function first. Post it as an answer and I'll upvote it too :)

Comment: With all respect, but such a question is quite simple. One needs only some experience in composing functions, which one aquires with any plotter, like the one in my comment.